# Rxjs: map method doesn't execute on combineLatest

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angularfire2

I'm trying to combine 2 Observable streams to 1 stream with `combineLatest`. 
Only, the `.map()` function doesn't work on the resulting stream. And with doesn't work, I mean that nothing is logged in the example below. On the other had, if I switch out the `.map()` function for a `.subscribe()` function, then everything works just fine. My observables come from firebase using the `angularfire2` library. I have also imported the `map` function and it works on other Observable streams.

```
const placeList = this._db.list(URL)
    .map(this.flattenJSON);
const placeImages = this._db.list(URL);
Observable.combineLatest(placeList, placeImages)
    .map(response => {
         console.log(response);
         return response;
    });
```

Does anyone know why the `subscribe` function works, and the `map` does not? And does anyone have advice on how I can merge 2 firebase Observable streams and map this stream. Mind you that the Observable streams resulting from `angularfire2` do not finish.

Comment: You still have to subscribe to the observable... Without subscribing you won't get notified.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting! I tried chaining a `.subscribe` after the `map` function and now it is logging! I didn't know this. Thanks for the advice, finally figured it out. If you create an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always subscribe to an observable if you want it to actually get executed. Just chain `subscribe()` after the map:

```
const placeList = this._db.list(URL)
    .map(this.flattenJSON);
const placeImages = this._db.list(URL);
Observable.combineLatest(placeList, placeImages)
    .map(response => {
         console.log(response);
         return response;
    })
    .subscribe();
```